# Will $.ajaxPrefilter work for form post?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using $.ajaxPrefilter to add key value pair to form data when an Ajax request is raised.

I'm seeing that this also works for normal form post request in MVC.

Is my understanding correct. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Ajax.BeginForm()` in `MVC`. It means each form post will be an ajax request. So `$.ajaxPrefilter` is taking place while posting form.